# How do I nest knockoutjs when comming from seperate js files?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have one html file with several js files included. These js files have knockout videmodels and I need to bind them nested in the html file.

Here's a sample:

HTML

```
<div id="container1">
   <span data-bind="html: name"></span>
   <div id="container2">
      <span data-bind="html: color"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
// Script comming from myScript1.js....
var person = new function() {
   var viewModel = function() {
      var self = this;
      self.name = ko.observable("John");
      return {
         name: self.name
      };
   };
   var vm = new viewModel();
   ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("container1"));
}

// Script comming from myScript2.js....
var colors = new function() {
   var viewModel = function() {
      var self = this;
      self.color = ko.observable("Red");
      return {
         color: self.color
      };
   }
   var vm = new viewModel();
   ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("container2"));
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MojoDK/023zL8ax/)

I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "html: function
>   (){return color }" Message: color is not defined

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with using anonymous objects for the view models. Could you try moving your JS below or above the html and see if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I see 2 ways to solve this problem. However in both solutions sequence of js files is important (not quite sure is it significant for you).

### Include Colors into Person

Use [with binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) for your inner html block:

Markup:

```
<div id="container1">
    <span data-bind="html: name"></span>
    <!--with binding to set context-->
    <div data-bind="with: colors">
        <span data-bind="html: color"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

First file:

```
// It's important to put this script first to make it available in person
var Colors = function() {
    return {
       color: ko.observable("Red")
    };
}
```

Second file:

```
var Person = function() {
    return {
       name: ko.observable("John"),
       // Create new instance of colors inside your person view model.
       colors: new Colors()
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new Person(), document.getElementById("container1"));
```

### Use component for your inner html

You can use [components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) to separate logic of particular blocks on the page. I would prefer this solution to make application more scalable.

Markup:

```
<div id="container1">
    <span data-bind="html: name"></span>
    <!--separate component as inner element-->
    <colors></colors>
</div>
```

First file (your component):

```
ko.components.register("colors", {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        return {
            color: ko.observable("Red")
        }; 
    },
    template: "<div id='container2'><span data-bind='html: color'></span></div>"
});
```

Second file:

```
var Person = function() {
    return {
       name: ko.observable("John")
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new Person(), document.getElementById("container1"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborating help!! The "component" way looks like a possible solution - I will test this. Thank you again. :)